# caching api for android application

Tags: android, caching

There is a part in my app which text and images of an article are downloaded from server and user can read a new article everyday. what I want is to store these contents and user won't need to download them again. Is there a api for that or I should handle all file writings and checking stuff? 
thanks in advanced.

Comment: You can use the java.io.File library and create a hidden directory (.SampleName), in internal or external storage. Refer to this. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 File cacheDir
 if(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/Android/data/<your app package>/.dir");
 else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
 if(!cacheDir.exists()) cacheDir.mkdirs();
```

Create a directory like this, it will check for sdcard or will store in internal storage.

Then save incoming stream like this.

```
 public void saveFile(InputStream is, File file){
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        copyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
 }
```